# Firebase Notification in Unity

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase messaging for my Unity project. I saw in Firebase Unity Reference have documentation for Notification.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/messaging/firebase-notification

I'm new in Unity, how can I add the Firebase Notification to the project, so it will push notification when message is received.

Comment: Questions asking to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer is to add `notification` json into `POST`, so the firebase will push notification when message is received.

```
{
"data": {
    "title": "This is my first unity project"
},
"to": "<tokenid>",
"notification": {
    "title": "Your Title",
    "text": "Your Text"
  }
}
```